# android CMake can not determine linker language for target

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake

I have created a very simple project about android and c++ in android studio.
the struct of project(module) is like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiQW8.png)

And build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shuyi.study.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"a
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path 'CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

when I start Gradle sync, it logged the informations:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwcjS.png)

I can not find the reason of this error.
Pleas give me some ides.Thanks!!!

Comment: Well one problem is that your file is called `native_zhang.cpp` and in your CMakeFile it's listed as `native-hang.cpp`. Fix that typo first.

Comment: I rename the cpp file to "native_zhang.cpp",but the result is same.

Comment: `CMakeLists.txt` code and build log should be **in the question post as text**, not *linked as images*. For files hierarchy textual representation is also preferred. (Actually, no needs in full hierarchy; just show where `CMakeLists.txt` and file caused the error are located.) Also, update code, files hierarchy and build log to the state with filename fixed.